# Indian prescription in America

Tags: usa, health

I live in India, and I have an anaphylactic allergy to bees. I have been advised to take Epipen epinephrine injections after being stung, but Epipens are not sold in India. Next month I am flying to New York, where Epipens are available for sale.

**Can I get a prescription for Epipens filled out by my doctor in India, and use that prescription in a pharmacy in New York to buy them?**

Additional details: I have a B2 class ten-year US visa and my doctor is registered and recognised worldwide.

Comment: FWIW, they appear to be available without a prescription in Canada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Your visa status is irrelevant, a prescription by an Indian doctor is just a piece of paper here.

However, if you visit a doctor here and explain the situation (for which having the Indian prescription will help) they'll no doubt give you a US prescription.  An Epipen isn't an item of abuse, I wouldn't expect trouble.